# Drain pipe through floor joist

Tags: drain, joists, kitchen-sink

I'm moving my sink. And I have to run my drain pipe through my floor joist or cabinets. My floor joist are 2×8's. Can I run a 2 inch pipe through them. And if i did run them through my joist would it make them weaker?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need to run _across_ (i.e. drill holes through) the joists, or _along_ the joists (i.e. between 2)? If drilling, will you be drilling near the top, middle, or bottom 1/3 of the joists, and how far from the ends of the joists? TL;DR - yes, drilling joists will make them weaker, the question is will there be _sufficient_ strength left, and we need those details to tell you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of your drain.  You can do it with a 1.5" PVC but a 2" really won't work.

### Allowable hole size in joist

The maximum allowed hole you can drill in a joist is 1/3rd the depth of that joist.  The actual depth of a 2x8 joist is 7.25" allowing only a 2.4" hole.

A 2" PVC pipe is 2.375" outer diameter (2-3/8") and you'll probably never get a 2.375" pipe into a 2.4" hole.  Milwaukee is the brand plumbers use in my area and Milwaukee's hole saw kits don't even come with 2-3/8" saws because they're not practical.

If your drain is 1.5", Family Handyman has a [helpful article](https://www.familyhandyman.com/project/how-to-drill-through-floor-joists/) showing you the right way to plan where to drill the hole in your joist.  Note you need to plan on a 1/4" slope per foot of drain line, too; so don't figure on going through very many joists in series with this drain, or you'll be too far from the center of the joists and compromise them.

### 1.5" drain capacity

A 1.5" drain is only enough for 3 [drainage fixture units](https://up.codes/s/drainage-system-sizing) (DFUs).  That's sufficient for your kitchen sink & garbage disposal ([DFUs per fixture table](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/drainage-fixture-unit-values-d_1077.html)) but it is not enough for an additional dishwasher to meet code.